# Detect that an activity has closed in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application I need to launch a SelectionActivity to select one of the options. Once the option has been selected I need to refresh another list on the MainActivity.

This is the code that I use to launch the SelectionActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectionActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SelectionActivity this is the code that receives the selected option an closes the activity:

```
selectedValue = adapter.getItem(position);
finish();
```

Now the application comes back to MainActivity but I don't know how to receive an event that the SelectionActivity has closed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Answer (score 13):

Quick snippet showing use of [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

```
private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 0xe110; // Or whatever number you want
// ensure it's unique compared to other activity request codes you use

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE)
        ActiviyFinishedNowDoSomethingAmazing();
}

public void onClickStartMyActivity(View view)
{
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class), MY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

More reading on [getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Comment: Did you choose 0xe110 just arbitrarily?

Comment: Yes it's arbitrary. Ideally should be a constant - I will update it to show this!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application's design you can refresh the list each time the Main activity is returned to by watching the onResume() or onRestart() events. In addition there is startActivityForResult(). All of these methods are in Activity.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 :**

1. Make `selectedValue` a static public variable.
2. In your `MainActivity` :

   ```
   void onResume() {
           result = SelectionActivity.selectedValue;
   }
   ```

**Solution 2 :**

If the `SelectionActivity`'s job is simply a selection from multiple options, Consider using [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult(), then override the onActivityResult() method.  There are a lot of examples one can google for just using the key word startactivityforresult.

Answer (score 0):

Use onActivityResult() or make selectedValue static. In MainActivity use the onResume method:

```
protected void onResume() {
    if(SelectionActivity.selectedValue != 0)
          newValue = SelectionActivity.selectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `onDestroy`:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.w("test", "active");
}
```